# Does FCM has a disadvantage that, if a device is offline, and message is triggered from FCM, the message is not received on device on coming online?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Long time ago, I used GCM in my Android app. It had a disadvantage. When a message was triggered from GCM to my Android app, if the device was not connected to internet, the message was not received by app.**On coming online also the message was not received**.**Does FCM have the same disadvantage**?

Comment: On coming online the message should received in GCM or FCM both.

Comment: But it did not happen that way. The message in GCM was not received by my app on coming online.

Comment: However, Priyank thanks for your info. Maybe there might have been some bugs in my app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the device is not connected to FCM, the message is stored until a connection is established (again respecting the collapse key rules). When a connection is established, FCM delivers all pending messages to the device. If the device never gets connected again (for instance, if it was factory reset), the message eventually times out and is discarded from FCM storage. The default timeout is four weeks, unless the time_to_live flag is set.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Comment: Thanks ealtaca for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Have your set 0 value of `time_to_live` parameter?

> Keep in mind that a `time_to_live` value of 0 means messages that
>   can't be delivered immediately are discarded.

On Android and Web/JavaScript, you can specify the maximum lifespan of a message. The value must be a duration from **0 to 2,419,200 seconds (28 days)**, and it corresponds to the maximum period of time for which FCM stores and attempts to deliver the message. Requests that don't contain this field **default** to the maximum period of **four weeks**.

Comment: I have not used FCM so far. I am planning to use it now. I heard of this time_to_live parameter just now. In GCM I might have set that as 0 unknowingly( if it was there.).